# Maximum velocity of interactions

Tags: field-theory, causality, interactions

In chapter 1, Section 1, para 7, of Landau & Lifshitz, *Classical Theory of Fields,* they argue that if a body moves faster than maximum velocity $V_m$ of interactions, that implies we can have an interaction with velocity greater than $V_m$, which in turn proves $V_m$ is not the maximum. Hence bodies have an upper bound on velocity. Can someone elaborate this argument?

Comment: It might help you more if you can focus in on the aspect of the argument that is causing you a difficulty.  Interactions are therised as exchanges of state limited only by the speed at which that exchanged state can be transfered betweeen the interacting bodies.

Comment: @JMLCarter I agree. But I was not able to imagine an intuitive example. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is clear that the existence of a maximum velocity of propagation of interactions implies, at the same time, that motions of bodies with greater velocity than this are in general impossible in nature. For if such a motion
>   could occur, then by means of it one could realize an interaction with a velocity exceeding the maximum possible velocity of propagation of interactions.

[L.D. Landau, E.M. Lifshitz "The Classical Theory Of Fields" (p. 1-2)](http://www.elegio.it/mc2/LandauLifshitz_TheClassicalTheoryOfFields_text.pdf)

If you could move from $A$ to $B$ faster than $V_m$, then you could take something (e.g. energy and momentum) from $A$ and give it to $B$. The fact that $B$ received this from $A$ would constitute an interaction of $A$ with $B$ with the velocity larger than $V_m$. This would be impossible, because we already know that $V_m$ is the largest possible velocity of interactions. For this reason you cannot possibly move faster than $V_m$.

Comment: Oh! I did not consider direct interaction via particle itself. This was helpful. Thanks. But I cannot upvote you as I don't have enough credits.